# Removing .html extension from URL on GitHub Pages

Tags: html, css, github-pages

I have a static website hosted on GitHub Pages and I am trying to remove the .html extension from the URL.
I understand that when using Jekyll, there is something called Permalink to do so. The thing is that I am not using Jekyll but only pure HTML & CSS.
I've also tried to create an .htaccess file at the root of my folder, but it doesn't seem to work on GitHub Pages.
I only have three html pages: index.html, projects.html and about-me.html.
When redirecting to the index.html, I can write `<a href="/"></a>` and then it'll remove the .html from the URL, but that's only specific to the index.
Any other way to do it for the other html pages?

[image: Project tree]

Comment: could you expatiate by showing the current way the URL is and how you intend it to be

Comment: So right now the url is looking like this: https://www.example.com/contact.html and I want to look like this: https://www.example.com/contact

Answer (score 3):

It already works and you don't have to do anything
I'm not sure if you are already aware of that or not but to remove .html extension from GitHub Pages all you have to do is remove .html extension from your links.

In other words it already works and you don't have to do anything. You don't have to use subdirectories, CNAME, redirects, Jekyll _config.yml, YAML front-matter or any other hack.

For example you can use:

https://rsp.github.io/gh-pages-no-extension/test1
instead of:

https://rsp.github.io/gh-pages-no-extension/test1.html
and it displays the same file. Just change the links in your links and that's it.

Comment: When I actually write <a href=“/contact”><a>, it doesn’t work. It says the page cannot be found.

Comment: Can you upload a photo of your project tree?

Comment: Done. On the main post.

Comment: I asked for it because i tought that your index.html was "nested" (i hope that's the correct term) and that was why you could get rid of the extension, but it's not, so it's really weird

Comment: yes, this works. see https://github.com/milahu/test-github-pages#no-file-extension